# How do I automate the built in "find and replace" function in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there a way to automate the find and replace function for MS Access?

I've got a lot of data I need to obscure (names and addresses), in a non-reversible way. It's going to an outside contractor that can't see the information (no NDA, etc. will do). But otherwise, I want the data to look as real as possible.

My plan right now is to do a find-n-replace on each character a-z and replace it with a random character. I recognise that chances are, I'll likely end up mapping two or more characters to the same value (which is not a bad thing in my books).

Ideally I'd like to have some kind of function that looks something like:

```
autoFindNReplace ("table name", "field name", _
                    "search char", random_alpha_generator(), _
                    DO_ALL_RECORDS)
```

And then I can run loop that on each field on each table that I have obscure.

My alternate methods are to:

- walk each table and obscure each field individually.
- try to come up with some sql statement that will do the same as the mythical autoFindNReplace I describe above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my solution:

```
Sub autoFindAndReplace(TableName As String, _
                    FieldName As String, _
                    Search As String, _
                    Replace As String)

Dim UpdateString As String

    UpdateString = ("update " & TableName & _
                        " set " & FieldName & _
                            " = replace (" & FieldName & ", " & _
                            """" & Search & """, """ & Replace & """)")

    CurrentDb.Execute (UpdateString)

End Sub
```

Then I loop on autoFindAndReplace with my random character generator, once for alphas and once for numerics.

Yes, I could have done it with multiple Update statements - however, I had a lot of tables and fields to deal with, and this made it look cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a quick hash function in a VBA module and call it from a SQL Update query.  Here's an example with table "Table1", and the field "address".  The hashField code was taken from [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=172530).

```
Sub MaskAddress()
    'Change 1234 to whatever key you'd like.
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Table1 SET address = hashField(address, 1234)"
End Sub

Public Function hashField(strIn As String, lngKey As Long) as String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strchr As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strIn)
        strchr = strchr & CStr(Asc(Mid(strIn, i, 1)) Xor lngKey)
    Next i
    hashField = strchr
End Function
```

Comment: ...and then you could write code to write SQL statements so you could do it in an automated fashion on multiple tables/fields.

Comment: I considered your suggestion, but I wanted to keep things looking sort-of real. i.e., "123 Fake Street" becomes -> "373 jdsi ndgadf" because there's going to be some parsing of the data going on. Thanks though +1